# Are a wgl contextfor FSAA multisampling and glVertexPointer/glColorpointer compatible

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

I hope this is the right lanuage to describe what I have done! I've created a WGL OpenGL context that supports FSAA. I have managed to render using shaders and VBOs through using

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, my_gl_vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data[0][0])*9, g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, my_gl_vertexbuffer);

glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  
        3,
        GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE,
        0,   
        (void*)0 
    );

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, my_gl_colorbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data[0][0])*9, g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);    
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, my_gl_colorbuffer);

glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                                // size
        GL_FLOAT,                         // type
        GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
        0,                                // stride
        (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle
```

and I get an output, without lighting because I have no lighting calculations in my shader cause I have 3 lights lighting the scene.

So it was suggested that I could use

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, g_vertex_buffer_data);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0,g_color_buffer_data);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle
```

which sort of works in a simple OpenGL context [that does not support FSAA]. In an FSAA WGL context [without any shaders loaded so I can use the fixed pipeline] all I get is the background colour that I cleared the screen to - it does not seem to render anything. Are glVertexPointer etc commands not supported in a FSAA WGL context? Or is it a case that with WGL context I have to use shaders?

Comment: Can you share the critical parts of your pixelformat/context setup, primarily the flags? It sounds like you might have picked up a Core Profile context. Also, does glGetError() return any error codes? I guess it's possible that vendors would only support the Core Profile in combination with certain other features, but I would find it surprising in this case.

Comment: `  const int iPixelFormatAttribList[] =
  {
   WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
   WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
   WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
   WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
   WGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB, GL_TRUE,
   WGL_SAMPLES_ARB,64,
   WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
   WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
   WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
   0 // End of attributes list
  };`

Comment: `const int iPixelFormatAttribList[] =
{
WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
WGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB, GL_TRUE,
WGL_SAMPLES_ARB,64,
WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
0 // End of attributes list
};`

Comment: `int iContextAttribs[] =
  {
   WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, iMajorVersion,
   WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, iMinorVersion,

WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
   0 // End of attributes list
  };

  int iPixelFormat, iNumFormats;
 wglChoosePixelFormatARB(hDC, iPixelFormatAttribList, NULL, 1, &iPixelFormat, (UINT*)&iNumFormats);`

Comment: @reto apologies for formatting - cant work out how to use it!

Comment: The forward compatibility flag in your context attributes is going to ruin your day if you make a habit of using deprecated things like `glColorPointer`. You need to remove that flag if you are not going to write modern GL code. Likewise, I am not aware of any GPU that supports 64x MSAA, only a handful even support 32x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You cannot use `glVertexPointer (...)`, `glColorPointer (...)`, etc... in a forward-compatible context.

Your problem has nothing to do with MSAA (though using 64x raises eyebrows), rather you have told GL to eliminate ***everything*** deprecated. A forward-compatible context is one step beyond *core* in terms of restrictivity. There are things that are deprecated but not removed in core, like wide lines... forward-compatible removes anything deprecated that is still valid in core.

Nevertheless, `glColorPointer (...)` is ***both***, deprecated and removed from core. You must remove the forward-compatible bit from your context flags to use it.